# Is there a standard to imitating an async filestream

Tags: c#, async

Im trying to replace an async filestream method, which is reading data from a Hid Device and feeding it to the UI. Ive considered writing the output into a log and then importing that log again, but that just seems to over complicated.

The whole reason behind this is to be able to test the program without the controller beeing connected. So either I create a test file which can be read into to create the desired output or i just completley randomize the dataset.

Is there another maybe better way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read from a pipe instead of the device. My guess is you won't have to change anything if you do that. Then you can write whatever you want to the pipe and retain all the async goodness.

Comment: ill attempt your advice over the weekend

Comment: Did you try? How did it go?

Comment: try yes, come right no. ive had to put this aside for the time beeing. something more urgent has come up